# Sendgrid not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I added `sendgrid` to my app on Heroku as my email sender, but each time user tries to sign up, the error occurs with the text "`www.mydomain.com" is currently unable to handle this request"`. Heroku logs does not show any error. Here is my `production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port           => "587",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => "<%= ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'] %>",
  :password       => "<%= ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'] %>",
  :domain         => "mydomain.com",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: Are you sending images in the email or strictly text?

Comment: strictly text, it's a confirmation email with devise @bkunzi

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with Devise's secret key needing to be set for production but I can't say for sure.

Comment: What is your logger level configuration right now? You can probably get more information by increasing that level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer, I had to set change initializer/devise from

```
 config. mailer_sender = mail
```

To

```
 config. mailer_sender = mail@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Add outside of the smtp_settings hash underneath everything you posted:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://somedomain.com' }
```

Also, make sure you added the environment variables for your username and password to Heroku!

Comment: all that is working fine,i just don't know where the error occurs on sendgrid because,heroku logs shows no error at all.